# How to use who vs whom in a complex sentence

Tags: grammar, who-whom

In these sentences how do I know whether I should use who or whom?

Sentence 1:

> This is the lady who/whom you said lives in the next house.

Sentence 2:

> This is the lady who/whom you say everybody respects a lot

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *This is the lady who/whom you said ____ lives in the next house*.
>
> [2] *This is the lady who/whom you say everybody respects ____ a lot.*

In [1] the pronoun is subject of the embedded "lives" clause, so it should be nominative "who".

In [2] the pronoun is object of "respects" so it should be accusative "whom". But nowadays people are less fussy about the distinction between "who and "whom" when the pronoun functions as object of a verb and regularly use nominative "who". In other words, both are correct in [2], but not [1].

Comment: To improve this answer could you explain what the ___ lines are for?

Comment: @whiskeychief The '___' notation is called 'gap''. Here, it indicates the position of the subject of "lives" in [1] and the object of "respects" in [2]. The gap derives its interpretation from "who(m)", which in turn derives its interpretation from "lady". Gapping is a standard procedure when analysing relative clauses. I'll edit my answer to include that info if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is:

"This is the lady who you said lives in the next house."

The lady is the subject so it is who, but anyone please correct me if I am wrong.